# mutate in r - how to use multiple OR conditions from one column

Tags: r

I'm using mutate and ifelse in r to create a new column. 
It's working, but was wondering if there's a simpler way of writing the "ors" here?

```
ifelse(school == 13 | school == 14 | school == 15, "private","public")
```

Comment: For this example, you could use `school %in% 13:15`

Comment: thanks! so quick, sorry edited numbers while you answered!

Comment: in case you're a noob: `ifelse(school %in% 13:15, "private","public")`